# python search serial data input

Tags: python, search, pyserial

I should start by saying I am very new to Python. Basically I am trying to make something that will read a couple of lines of serial data that gets pumped through every minute for a specific field and then print that value.

The part of the data I am after is the QNH field. e.g.:

```
QNH:1013.9
```

I am reading through the re library commands but it is all confusing with so many options for the search command.

So where I am now is as follows:

```
serial_line = ser.read(500)
qnhvalue = re.search(?I don't know what to put in here?, serial_line)

print(qnhvalue)
```

Comment: Should I be using match rather than search?

Comment: serial query answer is byte array, `import binascii; data=binascii.hexlify(ser.read(500))` now you got hexstring but where your starting point of serial answer ? You can't read serial data randomly ! Need start and end point(or time gap) for every reading (maybe your message not in answer (buffer overflow !))! Best way: 1) Clear buffer 2) Send query 3) Read answer 4)Close serial.

Answer (score 0):

`PySerial` is actually quite straight forward. `ser.read(500)` will read up to 500 bytes. You would then need to split your serial input into a list of values. If your separator is `\n` you can alternatively use `ser.readline()`.

In terms of regex I would even recommend to simply go with a simple split command `input.split("QNH:",1)[1]`. Otherwise you could also use `(?:QNH:).*`.

http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shortintro.html

Comment: there is no EOL on the input. What do you mean by split the serial input into a list of values? I can't just search the string?

Comment: Might be connected to buffering. Did you have a look at `io.TextIOWrapper`?